# Creating a nix username in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to Chef and i trying to create a  *nix username called your firstname.lastname using the 'user' Chef resource.  I haven't got a clue and really need some help.

```
package 'httpd' do
    action :install
end

service 'httpd' do
 action [:enable, :start]
end

file '/etc/motd'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
    content 'Hello world'
end
```

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`user` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html#syntax), such as:

```rb
user 'a user' do
  comment 'A random user'
  uid 1234
  gid 'groupname'
  home '/home/random'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  password '$1$JJsvHslasdfjVEroftprNn4JHtDi'
end
```

you might find [`users` cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/users) handy if you wish to manage users from a data bag